# Change line color of TextField in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, custom-controls

I am making component using ReactJS. In that i need to customize line color of TextInput with different color (one for success validation and another for failure validation)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default class CustomTextInput extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  name: '',
};
}
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <TextField
      style={{margin: 10}}
      id="standard-basic"
      label="Standard"
      error={false}
      inputProps={{maxlength: 12}}
      label="User Id"
    />
  </View>
);
}

[![success validation][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could use `material-ui`'s `error` prop. If you still want to change color, you should use `material-ui`'s `withStyles` or `makeStyles`.

Comment: I tried with below code, 

export default function CustomTextInput(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

const CustomTextInput = withStyles({
    root: {
      '& label.Mui-focused': {
        color: lableColor,
      },
      '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
        borderBottomColor: focusColor,
      },
      '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
        borderBottomColor: normalColor,
      },
    },
  })(TextField);
}

But focus is not working fine,If we keep withStyles outside function then it is working , but issue issue is if we keep outside then i cannot use props

Comment: It's really hard to read such code without formatting. I think you're a little confused with the `material ui` styling. I'll gladly take a look if you submit your updated code here (or edit your question). And please be more specific about what's not working and where :)